# Finding a basis for a subspace in $\;\Bbb R^4\;$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I know this might be a really simple question to ask but I just don't understand how to obtain the answer to this question. I've tried to understand subspaces (and even the difference between a space and a subspace) but I just can't seem to wrap my head around the concept. Any help with this question would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: A subspace of a vector space is simply a subset that is also a vector space in its own right.

Comment: A basis for the subspace of $\Bbb{R}^4$ spanned by the set $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ can be a subset of such set with the linearly independent vectors. Note that $v_1=v_2+v_4$, so that vector is a linear combination of others vector of your basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanically, the problem is straightforward. Make your vectors the columns of a matrix. Row-reduce the matrix and locate the pivot columns in the reduced form. The original vectors in those columns constitute a basis for the subspace spanned by the given vectors.

Comment: What do you mean by turning the vectors into columns of a matrix?

Comment: Construct a matrix having columns as your vectors i.e $\displaystyle A=(v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4)$

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solving:** Change this matrix to reduced row echelon form:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
        2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & -1 & -1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

which gives, (you should finally get 3 linearly independent columns).

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

So, the basis (B) is 
$$B=\lbrace v_1, v_2,v_4 \rbrace
$$
because 1,2 and 4 solved out to be the linearly independent columns.

**Understanding:** Imagine
$$
       v_1= \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, \ v_2= \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},\ v_3= \begin{bmatrix}
        4 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

These three vectors represent 3 different points in $ \mathbb R^2$. We don't know right now whether these 3 are linearly independent or not. But, clearly these are 3 differently looking vectors in $ \mathbb R^2$.
Also remember, span of 1 vector in $ \mathbb R^2$ is a straight line. Span of 2 different (or more accurately, linearly independent) vectors is a plane. Now, the rref of the example matrix will be
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 6 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
which means basis = $\lbrace v_1, v_2 \rbrace$

Because $v_3$ here was the extra information, we left it out while writing our basis. Our plane can be spanned by the linear combination of the 2 basis vectors $\lbrace v_1, v_2 \rbrace$ only.